# MINGW Windows - curl 7.59.0 missing sftp lib

Tags: curl, msysgit

I've install new version of msysgit and MINGW, but there is not support for sftp?! Could you please help me to add this?

```
$ curl -V
curl 7.59.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.59.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2o (WinSSL) 
zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4 nghttp2/1.31.0
Release-Date: 2018-03-14
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 
pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS Debug IDN IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL 
libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy MultiSSL Metalink
```

when I try access to sftp:
`fatal: Protocol 'sftp' not supported by curl, exiting...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I just [download some other curl.exe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/curlforwindows/files/?source=navbar) file and replace it in

`C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin`

SFTP work, but then there was another error.

`fatal: Could not get last commit. Network down? Wrong URL? Use 'git ftp init' for the initial push., exiting...`

So I've run with -v option:
`git ftp push -v`

error was:
`curl: (51) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK`

At last I've run `ssh-keyscan hostname.example.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`
[from here](https://serverfault.com/questions/783648/why-cant-curl-retrieve-the-ssh-host-key-key-none/802556#802556)

But it isn't help me, so I just use parameter `--insecure` and it works nicely now.